# Angular ng-options broken 1.4+

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

Angular < 1.4 works with ng-options shown as such:

```
<select ng-options="option.value as option.label for option in options" ng-model="selectedValue">
```

With the following array of options:

```
[{ value:"4_220588",label:"dropdown 1-test value 1"},{value:"4_220589",label:"dropdown 1-test value 2"}]
```

If you look at the resultant HTML is is as you would expect:

```
<select ng-options="option.value as option.label for option in options" ng-model="selectedValue" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched">
    <option value="" class="">-- SELECT ONE --</option>
    <option value="0" label="dropdown 1-test value 1">dropdown 1-test value 1</option>
    <option value="1" label="dropdown 1-test value 2">dropdown 1-test value 2</option>
</select>
```

As soon as you change the angular version to Angular 1.4+, the option value attribute get's messed up.  Here is the output with the same ng-options using a newer version of angular:

```
<select ng-options="option.value as option.label for option in options" ng-model="selectedValue" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-touched">
    <option value="" class="" selected="selected">-- SELECT ONE --</option>
    <option label="dropdown 1-test value 1" value="string:4_220588">dropdown 1-test value 1</option>
    <option label="dropdown 1-test value 2" value="string:4_220589">dropdown 1-test value 2</option>
</select>
```

What is the solution to getting the value to show up still as the index of the array?

Here is the plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/3CTUI9b9ntTGWhXDNQI5?p=preview

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-17

Comment: I just wanted to ask. Is this application in production? If so, is there something just absolutely demanding you upgrade? Generally speaking, once things are in production, you almost never upgrade your dependencies because they almost always come with breaking changes.

Comment: Yes we're trying to get to angular 1.5 component syntax and then gradually start using angular 2 components.

Comment: This is the expected outcome. Read the information at the link that @Claies posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application logic should not be sensitive to the `value` attribute in the dropdown, because `ng-model` will set the model correctly regardless of what is output in the HTML.  If you application logic does expect a specific format for this attribute, you have 3 ways to deal with this [breaking change](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-17).

1. Use `ng-repeat` instead of `ng-options`.  This is the least recommended option, as it changes the way the select lists work significantly.
2. Use a `track by` clause to enforce the key format that you are expecting, i.e. `option.value as option.label for option in options track by option.value`.  This presumes that `option.value` exists and is the value you wish to represent.  http://plnkr.co/edit/TSXfkpf1lhsE9QYa2NAc?p=preview
3. Change your application logic to expect the `hashkey` instead, or preferably correct the logic so that it only relies upon `ng-model`.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to use `ng-repeat` over the options.

```
<select ng-model="vm.selectedValue">
  <option value="" selected disabled>-- SELECT ONE --</option>
  <option ng-repeat="option in options" 
           value="$index" 
           ng-selected="option === vm.selectedValue">
        {{option.label}}
  </option>
</select>
```

Here is your updated [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/CCEQFwdL5mLxbRtGs6MJ?p=preview).

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work. The resulting value of vm.selectedValue is "$index" using your solution.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
<select ng-options="index as option.label for (index, option) in options2" ng-model="vm.selectedValue">
    <option value="">-- SELECT ONE --</option>
  </select>
```

On render the value of the selected option would be string:index but will output the desired value without the type included. Here is your edited  plunker with the expected result in the Selected Value:

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/MfiA8cMBz88606sFfaDI?p=preview)