# ng-options adding "string:" in value and not updating ng-model

Tags: angularjs

I have data such as this:

```
"RequirementLevels": {
 "285960000":"Black",
 "285960001":"Green",
 "285960002":"Blue",
 "285960003":"Purple"
}
```

And I have a Select like this:

```
<select ng-options="key as value for (key , value) in Variables.Template.RequirementLevels"
        ng-model="Variables.EditingNode.RequirementLevel"
        ng-model-options="{ debounce: 300 }"></select>
<span>"{{Variables.EditingNode.RequirementLevel}}"</span>
```

This produces the following html: 
[image]

Note the `string:` in front of each value in the select options. Using the below code I do not get the `string:` in the value.

```
<select ng-model="Variables.EditingNode.RequirementLevel">
     <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in Variables.Template.RequirementLevels" value="{{key}}">{{value}}</option>
</select>
```

My question is why am I getting the `string:` in the ng-option list and how do I make it go away.

**Update** because of comments: The reason I want to change this is because the ng-model value is not working when the value has `string:` in it. I assume this is because it does not match "string:123" in the option set with "123" from the model.

**Update 2**

This is the Html that creates the select.

```
<div class="form-group input-group">
    <label for="ReviewDone">Requirement level</label>
    <select ng-options="key as value for (key , value) in Variables.Template.RequirementLevels track by key"
            ng-model="Variables.EditingNode.RequirementLevel"
            ng-model-options="{ debounce: 300 }"></select>
    <span>"{{Variables.EditingNode.RequirementLevel}}"</span>
</div>
```

This creates the select with the options but does not select a default value. The span just below it that show the contents of the ng-model variable however works fine and prints the number "285960002" which is in the list of options, so it should be selected from the list to start with.

The above code generates this HTML:

```
<div class="form-group input-group">
    <label for="ReviewDone">Requirement level</label>
    <select class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-model="Variables.EditingNode.RequirementLevel" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 300 }" ng-options="key as value for (key , value) in Variables.Template.RequirementLevels track by key"><option selected="selected" value="?"></option><option value="285960000" label="Black">Black</option><option value="285960001" label="Green">Green</option><option value="285960002" label="Blue">Blue</option><option value="285960003" label="Purple">Purple</option></select>
    <span class="ng-binding">"285960002"</span>
</div>
```

Also selecting a different value in the select changes the value in the span, so it is updating the value but not reading it when it loads.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37706606/angular-ng-options-broken-1-4

Comment: The values you are seeing are the hash key for the item.  This is normal behavior for angular `ng-options`, and your application logic shouldn't be affected, since it doesn't change the value returned to `ng-model`.

Comment: @Claies: See update on question: I beleive the ng-model value is not working correctly with the string part present.

Comment: @Claies Hmm I might be wrong about that though as when im inspecting the variables after changing the drop down it is correct, but it wont set the dropdown to a value from the start, even though the variable assigned by ng-model clearly has a value matching to an option.

Comment: `ng-model` is not outputting the hashkey as per http://plnkr.co/edit/zDlwdHUTQU4q18PX0PF7?p=preview

Comment: @Claies agreed, it is not, I was wrong on that one. But the initial value of the ng-model variable is not being accepted even though it clearly matches an option value.

Comment: updated plunker, showing setting a default value: http://plnkr.co/edit/zDlwdHUTQU4q18PX0PF7?p=preview

Comment: it is true that adding `track by` will make the `string:` part of the hashkey disappear, but it seems like that's not really the issue you are having.

Comment: @Claies It would seem you are correct, adding it removed "string:" from the value but did not fix the problem I thought it would. I am printing out the value of the ng-model binding in a span just beside the select and this is showing one of the values that the select has. But the select is never set to a value to begin with.

Comment: can you show the portion of your code that is setting the default value? because it definitely seems to be working correctly in the plunker I created.

Comment: @Claies se update #2

Comment: where is the code that sets `Variables.EditingNode.RequirementLevel`? I have no problem setting the default value in the examples I have created.

Comment: This value comes from a REST request along with all other values displayed on the form (including the option values). The response is made using an angular service and then saved into the variable $scope.Variables.EditingNode in a .then() clause just before making the form visible with a ng-show.

Comment: ok so you are having a problem with the dropdown changing when the data is returned?  does it work if you remove the `debounce`?

Comment: @Claies Debounce makes no difference if its there or not. Also If i just copy paste the same select, the second one looses its value if I change the first one and vice versa. Its like its activly refusing to accept external value changes.

Comment: that isn't making any sense.  Is there *any* way that you can edit the plunker I provided and demonstrate the issue, or create your own plunker that works incorrectly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you want to make this additional string go away as you asked then use **track by key**.

```
<select ng-options="key as value for (key , value) in Variables.Template.RequirementLevels track by key"
```

See the plunker for reference

http://plnkr.co/edit/fi8lLyjkS0y3hfX7aeNI?p=preview

Comment: you probably want to `track by key`, not `value`;  `track by value` causes the dropdown to blank out the selection.

Comment: @Claies Aye, I tried track by key and it did remove the string:, but the problem I wanted to fix is still there as you said it would be.

Comment: what is the problem ?? thanks @Claies for pointing out that i have corrected that in post.